# Swagger Remove Extra Request Body Parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey, swagger

In [swagger](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs) core, how can I remove extra request body parameter?

I am using **fat** pojo / dto in my request, so I would like to hide some fields in certain end point.

Comment: Can you show us your code so we have something to go on?

Comment: are you able yo find solution for this issue?

Comment: any updates on this question?